# Restrict dragging within a div and a certain height within the restricted div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I'm using jQuery's `draggable({containment: });` to restrict dragging within a certain area. My question is how do I restrict dragging after a certain level of the Y axis within a restricted div?

```
jQuery("#map").draggable({
    containment: $('#range'),
    /////*
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        if(ui.position.bottom>375) {
          // stop dragging if exceed y axis 375 px ?
        }
    }
    */////
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since [**`containment`**](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-containment) option accepts array of coordinates, you could subtract *375px* from the height of the containment element.

(sample code. Exact coordinates depends on your CSS and HTML structure)

```js
$("#map").draggable({
    containment: [ 
        $('#range').offset().left,
        $('#range').offset().top,
        $('#range').offset().left + $('#range').width() - $("#map").innerWidth(),
        $('#range').offset().top + $('#range').height() - 275 
    ]
});
```

```css
#range{
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background: #ccc;
}

#map{
    padding:5px;
    max-width:36px;
    background:black;
    color:white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div id=range>
  <div id=map>MAP</div>
</div>
```

---

Yet another solution is to make a `#virtual-range` element inside `#range` element and set its height to `$('#range').height()-375`. Then use that `#virtual-range` as dragging region. And once again - all depends on your CSS and HTML structure.

```js
$('#virtual-range').css('height', $('#range').height()-275);

$("#map").draggable({
    containment: $('#virtual-range')
});
```

```css
#range{
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background: #ccc;
}

#map{
    padding:5px;
    max-width:36px;
    background:black;
    color:white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div id=range>
    <div id=virtual-range>
        <div id=map>MAP</div>
    </div>
</div>
```